# Ссылки на репозиторий в git

Tags: git

В `git` есть команда для того, чтобы хранить адрес репозитория под каким-нибудь сокращенным именем:

```
git remote add origin https://thisisanexample.git
```

Еще есть команда для изменения адреса репозитория:

```
git remote set-url origin https://thisistheexample.git
```

Но какую команду надо ввести, чтобы при записи адреса репозитория в какое-то имя, адрес по этому имени менялся, если оно(имя) уже есть и создавалось, если его не было ?

Comment: просто введите эти две команды одну за другой.

Comment: Не получится. Если имя origin уже существует, то при попытке сделать `git remote add origin ...` возникнет ошибка.

Comment: так проигнорируйте ошибку, и (цитирую) введите эти две команды одну за другой. и будет у вас именно то, что изложено в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но какую команду надо ввести, чтобы при записи адреса репозитория в какое-то имя, адрес по этому имени менялся, если оно(имя) уже есть и создавалось, если его не было?

например, такую:

```
$ git remote add имя url-хранилища || git remote set-url имя url-хранилища
```

---

здесь использован [управляющий оператор posix-совместимой оболочки `||`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_08):

```
$ команда1 || команда2
```

`команда2` будет выполнена только в том случае, если `команда1` завершится с не-нулевым кодом возврата (т.е., с ошибкой).